# K8s NodePort Port impassability in my kali node on VMware Fusion

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube

My k8s enviroment is deployed by minikube;

```
egrep -i 'vmx|svm' /proc/cpuinfo
vmx flags   : vnmi invvpid ept_x_only ept_ad tsc_.......

systemctl show --property=Environment docker
Environment=HTTP_PROXY=http://172.16.1.135:3128/ HTTPS_PROXY=http://172.16.1.135:3128/ "NO_PROXY=localhost,127.0.0.1,\$(minikube ip)"

minikube version                                                                                         
minikube version: v1.16.0
commit: 617f26b52345843a63d1a0715c4abf6625cb8862


k get pods -n kube-system                                                                                
NAME                               READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
coredns-54d67798b7-k6t5x           1/1     Running   2          120m
etcd-minikube                      1/1     Running   2          120m
kube-apiserver-minikube            1/1     Running   2          120m
kube-controller-manager-minikube   1/1     Running   3          120m
kube-proxy-86pv4                   1/1     Running   1          96m
kube-scheduler-minikube            1/1     Running   2          120m
storage-provisioner                1/1     Running   5          120m

k logs -f kube-proxy-86pv4 -n kube-system                                                                 ✔  1325  16:55:53
I0128 08:53:34.188328       1 node.go:172] Successfully retrieved node IP: 192.168.49.2
I0128 08:53:34.188524       1 server_others.go:142] kube-proxy node IP is an IPv4 address (192.168.49.2), assume IPv4 operation
I0128 08:53:34.391356       1 server_others.go:258] Using ipvs Proxier.
I0128 08:53:34.392942       1 server.go:650] Version: v1.20.0
I0128 08:53:34.393378       1 conntrack.go:100] Set sysctl 'net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_max' to 131072
I0128 08:53:34.393412       1 conntrack.go:52] Setting nf_conntrack_max to 131072
I0128 08:53:34.393483       1 conntrack.go:100] Set sysctl 'net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_established' to 86400
I0128 08:53:34.393528       1 conntrack.go:100] Set sysctl 'net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_close_wait' to 3600
I0128 08:53:34.395556       1 config.go:315] Starting service config controller
I0128 08:53:34.397797       1 config.go:224] Starting endpoint slice config controller
I0128 08:53:34.397839       1 shared_informer.go:240] Waiting for caches to sync for endpoint slice config
I0128 08:53:34.397979       1 shared_informer.go:240] Waiting for caches to sync for service config
I0128 08:53:34.498555       1 shared_informer.go:247] Caches are synced for service config
I0128 08:53:34.498572       1 shared_informer.go:247] Caches are synced for endpoint slice config
```

When i practice [Interactive Tutorial - Exposing Your App](https://kubernetes.io/zh/docs/tutorials/kubernetes-basics/expose/expose-interactive/)

I found the NodePort is not accessibility on my Node

```
k get svc                                                                                              
NAME                  TYPE        CLUSTER-IP    EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
kubernetes            ClusterIP   10.96.0.1     <none>        443/TCP          124m
kubernetes-bootcamp   NodePort    10.98.71.49   <none>        8080:30159/TCP   3m31s

curl 10.98.71.49:8080                                                                          
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 10.98.71.49 port 8080: Connection refused
telnet 10.98.71.49 8080                                                                                
Trying 10.98.71.49...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: No route to host
nc -nvv 10.98.71.49 8080                                                                               
Ncat: Version 7.91 ( https://nmap.org/ncat )
NCAT DEBUG: Using system default trusted CA certificates and those in /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt.
libnsock nsock_iod_new2(): nsock_iod_new (IOD #1)
libnsock nsock_connect_tcp(): TCP connection requested to 10.98.71.49:8080 (IOD #1) EID 8
libnsock nsock_trace_handler_callback(): Callback: CONNECT ERROR [Connection refused (111)] for EID 8 [10.98.71.49:8080]
Ncat: Connection refused.
sof -i:30159                                                                                          
curl 127.0.0.1:30159                                                                                   
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 30159: Connection refused
curl $(minikube ip):30159                                                                              
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.49.2 port 30159: Connection refused
```

while in the 'Interactive Tutorial - Exposing Your App', it is reachable;
and i practice The tutorial depends on 'Interactive Tutorial - Exposing Your App',
kube-proxy is noraml, and kubelet is normal too.

```
 journalctl -l -u kubelet                                                                        SIGINT(2) ↵  1340  17:04:31
Hint: You are currently not seeing messages from other users and the system.
      Users in groups 'adm', 'systemd-journal' can see all messages.
      Pass -q to turn off this notice.

-- Journal begins at Sat 2020-12-12 19:12:36 CST, ends at Thu 2021-01-28 16:51:26 CST. --
-- No entries --

 ifconfig docker0                                                                               
docker0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
        ether 02:42:01:c7:42:b8  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

route -n                                                                                       
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.80.2    0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
192.168.49.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 br-1bb4185a80c7
192.168.80.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 eth0
```

kubernetes-bootcamp service config:

```
   1   │ # Please edit the object below. Lines beginning with a '#' will be ignored,
   2   │ # and an empty file will abort the edit. If an error occurs while saving this file will be
   3   │ # reopened with the relevant failures.
   4   │ #
   5   │ apiVersion: v1
   6   │ kind: Service
   7   │ metadata:
   8   │   creationTimestamp: "2021-01-28T09:13:52Z"
   9   │   labels:
  10   │     app: kubernetes-bootcamp
  11   │   name: kubernetes-bootcamp
  12   │   namespace: default
  13   │   resourceVersion: "3495"
  14   │   uid: 471eca22-d276-45e5-b68f-aa21d461ea49
  15   │ spec:
  16   │   clusterIP: 10.111.216.90
  17   │   clusterIPs:
  18   │   - 10.111.216.90
  19   │   externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  20   │   ports:
  21   │   - nodePort: 32129
  22   │     port: 8080
  23   │     protocol: TCP
  24   │     targetPort: 8080
  25   │   selector:
  26   │     app: kubernetes-bootcamp
  27   │   sessionAffinity: None
  28   │   type: NodePort
  29   │ status:
  30   │   loadBalancer: {}
```

I swtich the kube-proxy mode to iptable and restart kube-proxy, iptables -F,
This is still the case.
I have no idea about this. can someone help me?

Comment: Could you please share your `kubernetes-bootcamp` service yaml by editing the question?

Comment: This configuration has been added，All the services I added in my node were the same situation.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Could you also `kubectl describe` that service?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

Based on the configs you provided it looks like you are using the wrong `NodePort` value while trying to curl into your service. It should be:

```
curl $(minikube ip):32129
```

instead of: `curl $(minikube ip):30159`.

Notice that the port should be taken from the `Service` definition:

```
  20   │   ports:
  21   │   - nodePort: 32129
```

There are some recommended steps that should be taken in order to debug this and any other similar problem in the future.

In order to [Debug Services](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-service/) you should try to answer these questions:

1. [Does the Service exist?](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-service/#does-the-service-exist): In your case we see that it does.
2. [Does the Service work by DNS name?](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-service/#does-the-service-work-by-dns-name): One of the most common ways that clients consume a Service is through a DNS name.
3. [Does the Service work by IP?](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-service/#does-the-service-work-by-ip): Assuming you have confirmed that DNS works, the next thing to test is whether your Service works by its IP address.
4. [Is the Service defined correctly?](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-service/#is-the-service-defined-correctly): You should really double and triple check that your Service is correct and matches your Pod's port. Also:

- Is the Service port you are trying to access listed in `spec.ports[]`?
- Is the `targetPort` correct for your Pods (some Pods use a different port than the Service)?
- If you meant to use a numeric port, is it a number (9376) or a string "9376"?
- If you meant to use a named port, do your Pods expose a port with the same name?
- Is the port's `protocol` correct for your Pods?

5. [Does the Service have any Endpoints?](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-service/#does-the-service-have-any-endpoints): Check that the Pods you ran are actually being selected by the Service.
6. [Are the Pods working?](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-service/#are-the-pods-working): Check again that the Pods are actually working.
7. [Is the kube-proxy working?](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-service/#is-the-kube-proxy-working): Confirm that `kube-proxy` is running on your Nodes.

I assume that you are still learning Kubernetes. These steps will not only help you narrow down the issue but also teach you how to approach these kinds of problems.